# Laravel 8 Relationship - Many to Many Best way

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent-relationship

I am in a strange situation where not getting clarity on how should I define the relationship between Models. I would like to know the experts' opinion on how should I approach designing the relationship.

Assume I have 3 tables:

1. Users (id, name, email, password...etc.)
2. Tags (id, user_id, name, created_at...etc.)
3. Contacts (id, name, email, dob, phone...etc.)

A user can have many tags (`$this->hasMany(Tag::class)` - *One To Many Relation*, right?)
A tag belongs to User (`$this->belongsTo(User::class)` - *Belongs To Relation*, right?)

A user has many contacts and contact belongs to many users (*Many to Many relationship*, right?).

Here I think I need another intermediate table `contact_user`.

A tag can have many contacts and contacts can have many tags (again, *Many to Many relationship*?).
And here again, I need an intermediate table `contact_tag`.

Now, the doubt I have is..is this the best way to approach creating relationships using `contact_user` and `contact_tag` table.

I want to access

1. users()->contacts()
2. tags()->contacts()
3. Users()->tags()

But in the future (just in case, if I might need it), I might want to access relations like.

1. contacts()->users()
2. contacts()->tags()

Please give me your opinion on how would you design your relationship assuming the above 3 tables and access the relationships I mentioned in the last?

Or do you think my approach by creating a `contact_user` and `contact_tag` table is a fine and efficient way to access the data behind the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

well ...the best way is having tow type relations...

first User and Contact have "[Many To Many (Polymorphic)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)
" with Tag,

and user have "[many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)" relation;

i think this is the most simple and clear option;

Comment: make sure read the laravel's official documents ;

Comment: Many to Many polymorphic relation does not apply here. I have read documentation a lot of time and knows that what I needed is not covered there. Please have a look at my question again and see what I want. User has many tags, user has many contacts, contacts are tagged by user. Tag belongs to user and tags have many contacts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert but based on the project i worked on , I think you need Many to Many relationship for both

- users & tags     -> the intermediate table `tag-user`
- users & contacts -> the intermediate table `contact-user`
- tags & contacts -> the intermediate table `contact-tag`
  *i don't think there is need the relation between the tags and the contacts*

> make sure read the laravel's official documents about the Many to Many relationship from    [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

##### To access the for example users -> tags

- in my project i add in the create blade an
  `<select class="custom-select selectpicker"  name="tags[]" id="inputGroupSelect01" multiple >`
  recognize the name attribute is an array for multiple tags
- we added in our intermediate table `tag-user`
  `$table->increments('id');`
  `$table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->nullable();`

  `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();`

  `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');`

  `$table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');`
- and in the my controller in the store function

  `$user= User::create($data);`

  `$user->tags()->attach($request->tags);`
- and in the update function instead of the attach() method , replaced it with the sync()

*hope this answer the question*